# Problem in changing the password of Linux VM on an ESXi hypervisor using Invoke-VMScript in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have created a Linux VM inside an ESXi hypervisor, and I need to change its password using an ESXi PowerShell command. For example:

```
$Script = \"echo '$OldPassword' | sudo -S passwd ubuntu <<< '$NewPassword\n$NewPassword'\";
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMName -ScriptText $Script -GuestUser ubuntu -GuestPassword $OldPassword;
```

But it returns the following error:
ScriptOutput

```
|  [sudo] password for ubuntu: Sorry, try again.
|  [sudo] password for ubuntu:
|  sudo: no password was provided
|  sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
|
```

I have tried a lot of possible scripts, but none of them are working. Is there any possible way to achieve this using a PowerShell command?

I tried this script

```
$Script = \"echo '$OldPassword' | sudo -S passwd ubuntu <<< '$NewPassword\n$NewPassword'\";
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMName -ScriptText $Script -GuestUser ubuntu -GuestPassword $OldPassword;
```

But it returns the following error:
ScriptOutput

```
|  [sudo] password for ubuntu: Sorry, try again.
|  [sudo] password for ubuntu:
|  sudo: no password was provided
|  sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```